# materialize modal select not displaying

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, materialize

I have a Django form rendering in a modal. The name field works fine but the 2 select fields are showing options even when they have their active class on.

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Create a Store</h4>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token%}
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="input-field">
                  {{ field.errors }}
                  {{ field.label_tag }} <br>{{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <button class="btn" type="submit">Create!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Script at bottom

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
$('select').material_select();
  });
```

the model Form

```
class StoreForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    store_size = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),
                               choices=models.SIZE_CHOICES, initial='1', required=True)
    subscriber_status = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),
                                      choices=models.SUBSCRIBER_LEVEL, initial='1',
                                      help_text="You can always downgrade or upgrade through your console")

    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
```

For extra clarity, what the inspector looks like on the element

```
    <div class="select-wrapper"><span class="caret">▼</span>
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-2de779c1-46cd-3271-5da4-889766247340" value="Silver"><select id="id_subscriber_status" name="subscriber_status" class="initialized">
    <option value="-1">Inactive</option>
    <option value="0">Free</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Silver</option>
    <option value="2">Gold</option>
    <option value="3">Platinum</option>
    </select></div>
```

No idea why readonly is true, as i've not set it to be so. I've fiddled with every attr in the console and tried adding styles like z-index and overflow and still nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be helpful to you.

```
class StoreForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Store
        fields = ['name','store_size','subscriber_status']
        widgets = {
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'store_size':forms.SelectMultiple(choices = models.SIZE_CHOICES,attrs={'multiple':'multiple','data-placeholder': 'Select Size'}),
            'subscriber_status':forms.SelectMultiple(choices = models.SUBSCRIBER_LEVEL,attrs={'multiple':'multiple','data-placeholder': 'Select Status'})
       }
```